# Adding security to OPC UA python server/client (Asyncua)

Tags: python, authentication, security, python-asyncio, opc-ua

I'm new to OPC UA and Python, but with the asyncua examples, I created the example that I need for a real project. Now I need to add security to the server and client, and for now, using a username and password is fine.

Here is my functional code without security. If someone knows what functions I need to use to create two users, one with admin privileges and the other with none, please let me know.

```
import asyncio
from asyncua import Server, ua
from asyncua.common.methods import uamethod
from asyncua.common.structures104 import new_struct, new_struct_field

@uamethod
def func(parent, value):
    return value * 2

async def main():
    
    server = Server()
    await server.init()
    server.set_endpoint("opc.tcp://localhost:4840/freeopcua/server/")

    uri = "http://examples.freeopcua.github.io"
    idx = await server.register_namespace(uri)

    myobj = await server.nodes.objects.add_object(idx, "MyObject")
    myvar = await myobj.add_variable(idx, "MyVariable", 0.0)
    
    await server.nodes.objects.add_method(
        ua.NodeId("ServerMethod", idx),
        ua.QualifiedName("ServerMethod", idx),
        func,
        [ua.VariantType.Int64],
        [ua.VariantType.Int64],
    )
    
    struct = await new_struct(server, idx, "MyStruct", [
        new_struct_field("FirstValue", ua.VariantType.Float, 0.0),
        new_struct_field("SecondValue", ua.VariantType.Float, 0.0),
        new_struct_field("ThirdValue", ua.VariantType.Float, 0.0),
        new_struct_field("FourthValue", ua.VariantType.Float, 0.0),
        new_struct_field("FifthValue", ua.VariantType.Float, 0.0),
    ])
    
    custom_objs = await server.load_data_type_definitions()
    
    mystruct = await myobj.add_variable(idx, "my_struct", ua.Variant(ua.MyStruct(), ua.VariantType.ExtensionObject))
    await mystruct.set_writable()
    await myvar.set_writable()
    
    print("Starting server!")
   
    async with server:
   
        while True:
        
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
            
            n_struct = await mystruct.get_value()
            var = await myvar.read_value()

            print ("\n%f\n%f\n%f\n%f\n%f\n%f" % (var, n_struct.FirstValue,  n_struct.SecondValue, n_struct.ThirdValue, n_struct.FourthValue, n_struct.FifthValue))

try:
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    
except RuntimeError:
    loop = None
    
if loop and loop.is_running():
    print('Async event loop already running. Adding coroutine to the event loop.')
    tsk = loop.create_task(main())
    tsk.add_done_callback(
        lambda t: print(f'Task done with result={t.result()}  << return val of main()'))

else:
    print('Starting new event loop')
    result = asyncio.run(main(), debug=True)
```

I tried to use the encryption example from Asyncua, but I can't make it work. So, I tried to read the functions of the main code from Asyncua server and do something by myself, but I only got errors.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a class that implements get_user

```
class CustomUserManager:
    def get_user(self, iserver, username=None, password=None, certificate=None):
        if username == "admin":
            if password == 'secret_admin_pw':
                return User(role=UserRole.Admin)
        elif username == "user":
            if password == 'secret_pw':
                return User(role=UserRole.User)
        return None
```

To use the manager in your code:

```
user_manager = CustomUserManager()
server = Server(user_manager=cert_user_manager)
await server.init()
server.set_endpoint("opc.tcp://localhost:4840/freeopcua/server/")
```

Comment: Ok, so this works, I can open the server and If I try to connect I get "User does not have permission to perform the requested operation."(BadUserAccessDenied)" but if I add to the client code the client.set_user('admin') and client.set_password('secret_admin_pw') I get the same error, and I dont know if I need to do something else.

Comment: Witch OPC Watch I can connect with the server using the users and passwords

Comment: @Hrathen23 Does your server require a certificate from the client ?

Comment: For now no, first I want to connect with the client code only with user and password, and after that try to add a certificate. In theory with OPC Watch im connecting without certification, only with the user and password.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so for some reason, if I use:

```
async with Client(url=url) as client:
```

to connect as the client to the url the connection starts automatically and I cant set the username, so what I did is:

```
client = Client(url=url)
client.set_user('admin')
client.set_password('secret_admin_pw')

await client.connect()
```

And now it works.